# ListTile single selection (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

For sure it's a simple solution fot this, but I can't figure out it - I quite new in flutter - still. What's the problem?

I have alert dialog with 4 list tiles which supposed to work as selectors for gps radius, however I have a problem with single selection. Now while one is selected - all are selected in same time. So i need to find a way how to make single selection for each of them (if one is selected rest should be unselected), and then pass it's value, eg. 10, 25 etc. while "Select" button is pressed.

```
class RadiusSelectorDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  RadiusSelectorDialog({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RadiusSelectorDialogState createState() => _RadiusSelectorDialogState();
}

class _RadiusSelectorDialogState extends State<RadiusSelectorDialog>
    with TitleDescriptionTextMixin {
  bool selected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      scrollable: true,
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
      title: Center(child: smallerBoldText('Select radius:', fontSize: 15.0)),
      content: Column(
        children: [
          Divider(
            color: Colors.grey,
            height: 2.0,
          ),
          CustomListTile(
            label: '10 km',
            selected: selected,
            onSelect: () => _onSelect(selected),
          ),
          CustomListTile(
            label: '25 km',
            selected: selected,
            onSelect: () => _onSelect(selected),
          ),
          CustomListTile(
            label: '50 km',
            selected: selected,
            onSelect: () => _onSelect(selected),
          ),
          CustomListTile(
            label: '75 km',
            selected: selected,
            onSelect: () => _onSelect(selected),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16.0))),
      actions: [
        FlatButton(
            child: Text('Select',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: LegionColors.primaryRedHigh,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            })
      ],
    );
  }

  void _onSelect(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      if (selected == false) {
        selected = true;
      } else {
        selected = false;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

My custom listTile for selection.

```
class CustomListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final bool selected;
  final Function onSelect;

  const CustomListTile(
      {Key key,
      @required this.selected,
      @required this.onSelect,
      @required this.label})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ListTile(
          title: Center(
              child: Text(label,
                  style: selected == false
                      ? TextStyle(color: Colors.black)
                      : TextStyle(
                          color: LegionColors.primaryRedHigh,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ))),
          selected: selected,
          onTap: onSelect,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16.0))),
        ),
        Divider(
          color: Colors.grey,
          height: 2.0,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same variable `selected` to identify whether the item is selected for all the items.
Here is what happens,

1. One items is tapped
2. setState -> selected -> true
3. All the items update themselves to be `selected`

To avoid it

1. you can move the identifier inside the `CustomListTile` and make it StatefulWidget.
2. Or if you have to maintain the selection status in the parent, you can use a `Map` implementation

```dart
  HashMap<String, bool> selectedState = new HashMap();

  void updateSelectionStatus(String selectedTileId, bool status) {
    setState(() {
      selectedState[selectedTileId] = status;
    });
  }
```

And then you can use it like this

```dart
CustomListTile(
            label: '75 km',
            selected: selectedState['your-unique-id'],
            onSelect: () => updateSelectionStatus('your-unique-id', !selectedState['your-unique-id']),
          )
```

Comment: Devayan Sarkar - seems to be a good solution (with map), however, now it shows that selected value is null - I even change customtile property to be set "flase" by default, but selectedState clears it somehow and pass null value to it.

Comment: Did you populate the `selectedState` ?

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      selectedState['tile1'] = false;
      selectedState['tile2'] = false;
      selectedState['tile3'] = false;
      selectedState['tile4'] = false;
    });
  }
```

Comment: It's almost prefect now :) I need to block other tiles to be selected. To make it single selection list. I'm thinking about switch statement.

Comment: If you are trying to select only one of them. Then I would suggest an alternate approach.
```dart
int selectedItem = 0 ;

void updateSelectedItem(int index){
    setState(() {
              _selectedIndex = index;
            });
}

// Use it like this

CustomListTile(
            label: '75 km',
            selected: 1 == selectedItem,
            onSelect: () => updateSelectedItem(1),
          )

CustomListTile(
            label: '85 km',
            selected: 2 == selectedItem,
            onSelect: () => updateSelectedItem(2),
          )


```

Answer (score -2):

Check its working code on official Flutter website https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile/selected.html